# display sharepoint app in outlook 2013 and owa

Tags: sharepoint, apps-for-office

I have created an SharePoint- hosted app and using office API’s within the start page. The app is added in exchange and enter image description hereapp web links are referred in appmanifest.xml.

1) On click of link, page renders as expected in **OWA** every time except for 1st time, following error occurs .

> "App Error Something went wrong and we couldn't start this app. Please
>   try again later or contact your system administrator." console log
>   shows:“Uncaught Sys.ArgumentNullException: Sys.ArgumentNullException:
>   Value cannot be null.Parameter name: conversationId “ in 
>   outlook-web-16.00.js:

It works as expected in subsequent calls.

2) The app doesn’t load in outlook client. Following error occurs in Microsoft Office Alerts :

> App Error This app could not be started. Close this dialog to ignore
>   the problem or click "Restart" to try again. P1: Apps for Office P2:
>   15.0.4719.1001 P3: 0x80010105 P4: following is displayed in fiddler: X-MSDAVEXT_Error: 917656;  HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized ........ ..
>   Access+denied.+Before+opening+files+in+this+location%2c+you+must+first+browse+to+the+web+site+and+select+the+option+to+login+automatically.
>   .....

All suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: I have the same problem, It would be helpful if you can share what you have done for resolution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This issue appears when we debug outlook apps in debug mode and the app exceeded the allotted time to load required office 365 js files into your app.

One thing i am doing to avoid this issue, in the browser you are using to authenticate using o365 account, check the box to login automatically to save time and load client js files faster post authentication step.